# How to project a foam trail on dynamically changing mesh

Tags: c#, unity, rendering

I am trying to create water, and right now I got it through dynamically generating waves on a mesh. But now I want to make my boat manipulate these waves, and cause a Kelvin Wake on top of this. [image]

Fact is I generate the water using different tiles, repeating the same pattern dynamically. So How would I generate this on top of a dynamically generated mesh(plane)? Without also manipulating the other tiles (planes)?

Comment: I'm not sure if the developers chime in, but there's an extended discussion of World of Warship's implementation here:  http://forum.worldofwarships.eu/index.php?/topic/12699-bow-wave-and-boat-wake-improvement/

Comment: As a side note, you might want to make these waves fade after a while as opposed to going on for such a long distance.

Comment: @Lolums I was planning to make the trail last through out the visual range of 1000 UU (unity units). After which I wanted to make them fade away

Comment: I don't think you find an answer here, I suggest to find one of the graphic team worked on warship game, and see if he has a blog then post a question upthere, peoples who knows how to model this kind of expert features are lower than both hands fingers in number, but if you succeed to find I will be happy to up vote your selfs answer too.

Comment: recently I come across this article, check if it helps you http://www.habrador.com/labs/unity-boat-tutorial/7-water-wakes/

Comment: @idurvesh This works flawless with a single plane type of water, in my scenario as described there are several planes. My original implementation as described above is a twist on the Unity Community water.

Comment: there is a lot of scope for how you might be implementing what you describe... but are you attached to this particular implementation? id be inclined to generate the water heights using the 'old 2d water convolution' trick - basically a 2d blur and subtract the original every frame - if you don't know about this look into it - making things interact with it very easy (and produces this effect amongst others)... and although it is a trick it does match up with a numerical solution to a wave equation by finite differences. :)

Answer (score 1):

How I would go about something like this is to make a grid, like a sort of heightmap. And if a mesh is in the grid try to calculate (on a 2d plane) how deep it will be in the water, then, based on this heightmap, generate the waves in the water.

Comment: This answer would benefit from more detail about how you would actually go about these calculations, given a moving boat. It also doesn't address the asker's question about limiting the tiles affected by the modification.

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 suggestions. 
first: You might try and create the effect using a particle system.
second: You can try and use TrailRenderer for a trail.
third: You could try and create a mesh with such trail shape, parent it to the boat and depending on the speed/distance to increase the size of it on one/two axes.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate a bit more on your second point? The first option sounds fairly plausible, at-least for the foam part. As for your third point, taken into account that the water surface won't be flat, how would this be applied on the crossing point of planes?